# Hot to pass a TextView by View.setTag () from Adapter and Animate it Later

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to animate my textView when I fling right. For the act of remove the textView I associate an animate.

On getView on myAdapter I did this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }
    Card card = deck.get(position);
    TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    tv.setText(card.toTimeString());
    vi.setTag(tv);
    return vi;
}
```

In my list Activity, I recovery the TextView tapped with pointToPosition and Try to animate it, but not happens: The onFling method is called, but the animation don't work.

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    int position = getListView().pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY());
    if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()){
        return fling (position);
    }else{
        return reverseFling (position);
    }

}

private boolean fling(int position) {
    View view = getListAdapter().getView(position, null, getListView());
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.getTag();
    tv.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(230).translationX(333);
    return true;

}

private boolean reverseFling(int position) {
    Log.i(tag, "reverseFling");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you try getting the textview using view.findviewbyid method and then compare the text in the view and the card value at tht position, just incase

Comment: Yes and no, cause the text can be equals in two textviews. but I don't realize why I cannot animate the textview the way I did above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved It using this:

```
    View view = getListAdapter().getView(position, null, getListView());
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.getTag();
    TextView theTv = (TextView) findViewById(tv.getId());
    theTv.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(230).translationX(333);
    return true;
```

But still dont´t know why I cannot animate tv TextView directly.